# How to add variable to the loaded file

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have `id_p` variable that should be sent along with the uploaded file on the server.

There are four such files to load and each must be loaded with this information from the variable

```
$(function () {

var id_p = document.getElementById('primarie').value();
console.log(id_p);

$('#dxfUpload').fileupload({
    url: 'upload-manager.php',
    start: function (e, data) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
    }
});


$('#csvUploadGA').fileupload({
    url: 'upload-manager-csv.php',
    start: function (e, data) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
    }
});

$('#csvUploadB').fileupload({
    url: 'upload-manager-B.php',
    start: function (e, data) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "block";
    },
    done: function (e, data) {
        document.getElementById('loading').style.display = "none";
        addLayer();
    }
});
});
```

Thank you and wait for the response.

Comment: In the URL part you can send your variable as a query string and later read that on the server, something like this :  url: 'upload-manager.php?id_p ='+id_p ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to also append your id_p in your form:

```
$('#img-upload').change(function(e){
 var id = $("input[name=id]").val();
 var file = this.files[0];
 var form = new FormData();
 form.append('img-upload', file);
 form.append('uploaded-id', id); //Here is the appended id_p 
  $.ajax({
    url : 'upload.php',
    type : 'POST',
    cache : false,
    contentType : false,
    processData : false,
    data : form,
    success : function(response) {
         $("#responsePanel").css({'display':'block'}).hide().html(response.html).fadeIn(1000);
    }
 });
});
```